# Passing a function as argument to another function

Tags: matlab

I see a function passing like

```
sigma = 3*e-2
svmTrain(...,@(X,y)gaussianKernel(X,y,sigma),...);
```

What is going on with such a function passing, would someone explain ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax `@(X,y) gaussianKernel(X, y, sigma)` creates an [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/examples.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/matlab/anondemo.html) by binding the third argument of this existing function `guassianKernel(X, y, s)` to specifically be the value `sigma`.

If you inspect the `svmTrain` function signature, you'll see that it allows passing in a function, which is where this anonymous function is going.

Comment: so the third argument is bonded statically and X y is bonded at run time?

Comment: The third argument is bonded to be a constant, yes. If you're familiar with `partial` in Python (or analogues in functional computing) it's like that. The other arguments are free to be passed in and evaluated during the course of `svmTrain`. So it's like you get a new phantom function back that has two arguments instead of three, but does everything else exactly the same way as before, using the passed-in constant for the third argument all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Two things happen here:

First is function passing. For example, you had a function `foo` in your code, and you want to pass it as a parameter. In this case, you use `@` operator.

```
function MainScript
    goo(@foo);     
end

function goo(fHandle)
    fHandle();
end

function foo
    disp('Hello world!');
end
```

The second is anonymous functions. Anonymous function is a function much like every other function, except that it is defined at runtime, it has no name, and it binds to itself a local copy of variables that are passed to it. (For more information, see [Closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29)). For example:

```
 function MainScript
     foo = @() (disp('Hello world!'));
     goo(@foo);   
 end
```