# Passing a function as a parameter in a MATLAB function

Tags: function, matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Passing a function as argument to another function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709226/passing-a-function-as-argument-to-another-function)

Below is a simple code for the bisection method. I would like to know how to be able to pass in any function I choose as a parameter instead of hard coding functions.

```
% This is an implementation of the bisection method
% for a solution to f(x) = 0 over an interval [a,b] where f(a) and f(b)
% Input: endpoints (a,b),Tolerance(TOL), Max # of iterations (No).
% Output: Value p or error message.

function bjsect(a,b,TOL,No)
% Step 0
if f(a)*f(b)>0
    disp('Function fails condition of f(a),f(b) w/opposite sign'\n);
    return
end
% Step 1
i = 1;
FA = f(a);
% Step 2
while i <= No
    % Step 3
    p = a +(b - a)/2;
    FP = f(p);
    % Step 4
    if FP == 0 || (b - a)/2 < TOL
        disp(p); 
    return
    end
    % Step 5
    i = i + 1;
    % Step 6
    if FA*FP > 0
        a = p;
    else
        b = p;
    end
    % Step 7
   if i > No
       disp('Method failed after No iterations\n');
       return 
   end
end
end

% Hard coded test function
function y = f(x)
y = x - 2*sin(x);
end
```

I know this is an important concept so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @H.Muster Yes, you're right. I'll flag it. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method is using [anonymous functions](http://www.mathworks.com.au/products/matlab/examples.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/matlab/anondemo.html). In your example, you would define your anonymous function outside `bjsect` using:

```
MyAnonFunc = @(x) (x - 2 * sin(x));
```

You can now pass `MyAnonFunc` into `bjsect` as an argument. It has the object type of function handle, which can be validated using `isa`. Inside `bjsect` simply use `MyAnonFunc` as if it is a function, ie: `MyAnonFunc(SomeInputValue)`.

Note, you can of course wrap any function you've written in an anonymous function, ie:

```
MyAnonFunc2 = @(x) (SomeOtherCustomFunction(x, OtherInputArgs));
```

is perfectly valid.

**EDIT:** Oops, just realized this is almost certainly a duplicate of another question - thanks H. Muster, I'll flag it.